# Loop through a R matrix row-wise and print elements

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Got a basic R for-loop matrix question:

My matrix looks something like this:

```
2    4    3
1    5    7
```

All I want is to print these elements row wise and not column wise. The answer should be like `2 4 3 1 5 7`. All I try I get the result column wise i.e `2 1 4 5 3 7. Since m just beginning R wondering if it can be done by just for-loop which loops column wise and not row-wise

Comment: `apply(m,1,print)`

Answer (score -1):

```
m <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), 2, 3, byrow=T)
as.vector(m)
```

or

```
c(m[1, 1:3], m[2, 1:3])
```